# Convergence of the following series

Tags: number-theory

Does this series converge?
$$
\sum_{m \in S_{a,b}} \frac{1}{\varphi(m)}\;,
$$
where $S_{a,b}=\{ n \in \mathbb{N}: n \equiv a\bmod b \}$, for fixed $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$ with $\gcd(a,b)=1$  and $\varphi$ is the Euler totient function.

Comment: What is $\;a,b,\varphi\;$ ...? Even in the last one is Euler's Totient Function, $\;a,b\;$ still are unknown...

Comment: @DonAntonio: I edited again the question.

Comment: But then $\;a,b\;$ are *fixed*, right? Perhaps denoting $\;S_{a,b}\;$ would make this clearer...

Comment: @DonAntonio: yes, you're right, thanks

Answer (score 3):

Assuming we are talking about Euler's phi function and an arithmetic sequence in which the first term and common difference are co-prime, then the series does not converge:

It is easy to see that the series $$\sum_{m\in S}\frac{1}{m} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{a+bk}$$

diverges, and the terms of your series are bigger than the corresponding terms of the series above, since $\varphi(m)<m$ for any $m>1$.

Comment: @Old John: Perfect! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Vadim You might like to post that as a new question?

Comment: @GIANCANE You are welcome - glad to be able to help.